# "Tomar" tem origem saxônica?

Tags: origem

O verbo "tomar" está [ausente](http://200.144.244.242/~delpo/consulta/consulta_hiperlema.php?hiperlema=tomar) do DELPo (Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa) e o Priberam [afima](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/tomar) que o verbo é

> De origem obscura

Também o site Origem da Palavra [afirma](https://origemdapalavra.com.br/palavras/tomara/), assim como o Michaelis, que a origem do verbo "tomar" é desconhecida.

Contudo o [Novo dicionário da língua portuguesa](https://archive.org/details/DicionrioDeL.P1913/page/n2007) (1913) de Candido de Figueiredo (também [aqui](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/31552/) e [aqui](https://pt.thefreedictionary.com/tomar)) coloca que a origem seria o saxônico *tômian*, que [significa](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/48908567.pdf) (cf. também [aqui](http://jillian.rootaction.net/~jay/world_faiths/www.northvegr.org-r/lore/latinsaxon/l.html) ou [aqui](http://lexicon.ff.cuni.cz/pdf/pgmc_torp/pgmc_torp_20060530.pdf)) *libertar*.

A possível origem saxônica é também mencionada no [Dicionário Etimológico Da Língua Portuguesa, Tomo 1](https://archive.org/details/AntenorNascentesDicionaroEtimologicoDaLinguaPortuguesaTomoI/page/n535) (1955)​ de Antenor Nascente, juntamente outras fontes, que oferecem outras possibilidades ou confirmam a origem obscura:

> TOMAR — A. Coelho derivou do germânico em dúvida; cita o ant. saxão *tômian*, libertar (Diez, *Gram*, I, 64, *Dic.*, 321). Leite do Vasconcelos, *Lições de Filologia Portuguesa*, 443, declara que a etimologia ainda não está suficientemente averiguada; manda ver Körting,
>   *Lat._rom.* Wb, § 9756. C. Michaëlis, *Glossário do Can. da Ajuda*, declara verbo privativamente peninsular, usado desde os primeiros monumentos da literatura; pertence provavelmente ao *sermo rusticus*. Bourciez, *Ling. rom., 194, declara de origem desconhecida. M. Lübke, *REW*, 8975, prende á onomatopeia *tum(b)*, com idéia de queda, e acha inverossimil ligar a *mutuare* (*Romanische Forschungen*, I, 237).

Me pergunto se existe alguma fonte mais atual a respeito.

Comment: Nem mesmo os hispanofalantes [têm mais certeza da sua origem inclusiva](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?tomar). Não tenho muita confiança em nenhuma dessas explicações que mencionam lá.

Comment: Pois é, @tchrist, há boa razão para os dicionários listarem como de origem obscura.

Comment: Consultaste o "Dicionário Etimológico da língua Portuguesa" do José Pedro Machado? É posterior aos dicionários que citaste (excepto o da USP que não conheço e sobre cuja qualidade não me posso pronunciar.)

Comment: @bad_coder Não chequei, vou ver consigo acesso no início de janeiro.

Comment: @stafusa agora não tenho esse dicionário aqui comigo. Senão já te dizia o que lá figura nesse verbete.

Comment: A melhor explicação até agora: https://books.google.com/books?id=StL6DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=conjecture+%2B+tomar+%2B+spanish+and+portuguese&source=bl&ots=jp7i0fvdkK&sig=ACfU3U0fmVwf80s8O1xydcIYR6NW5EHa4w&hl=en&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizhvuo89PmAhXJct8KHbhBDYAQ6AEwDHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=conjecture%20%2B%20tomar%20%2B%20spanish%20and%20portuguese&f=false

Comment: @lambie Muito boa referência! Sem dúvida suficiente para embasar uma resposta.

Comment: Ainda ninguém mencionou: Tomar também é Toponímio.

Comment: Não sei se ajuda, mas existe uma cidade chamada Tomar em Portugal.

Comment: Puf, bounty pó teto... tinha esperança que os estudiosos da gramática fossem mais gananciosos. :'(

Comment: Uma pena que o Lambie não tenha tentado escrever uma resposta a referência que ele encontrou é muito boa.

Answer (score 1):

A origem de tal verbo é desconhecida, há quem diga que possa vir do latim *autumāre*, mas não é conclusivo.

O verbo, no entanto, pode ter vindo de origem germânica durante a ocupação da Península Ibérica após a queda do Império Romano do Ocidente. A origem, porém, pode ser **germânica**, provavelmente visigótica/sueva, não "saxônica" como falas na pergunta. Os saxões foram um povo que habitava o norte do que hoje é a Alemanha e, até hoje, o baixo alemão é o famoso saxão.